# How to Assign true condition's value to a variable outside of if else condition in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, eloquent

I am trying to assign some value to a variable named `$bonus` in if-else conditions and then I am trying to call `$bonus` outside of the if-else condition so the true condition's variable should be called automatically. I have tried this code but it is giving me an error on debugging mode of laravel

Error:

> Undefined variable: bonus

Code:

```php
<?php
if ($data->lend_amount >= 50 && $data->lend_amount <= 500) {
    $bonus = ($data->lend_amount * 4) / 100;
} else if ($data->lend_amount >= 500 && $data->lend_amount <= 50000) {
    $bonus = ($data->lend_amount * 5) / 100;
}

if ($user_b_update) {
    Transaction::create([
        'user_id' => $data->user_id,
        'trans_id' => rand(),
        'time' => Carbon::now(),
        'description' => 'Matching Bonus Of ' . $bvp . ' Users',
        'amount' => $bonus,
        'new_balance' => $newacc_bal,
        'new_earning' => $newbal,
        'type' => 4,
        'charge' => 0
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define `$bonus`

```
$bonus = 0;

if ($data->lend_amount >= 50 && $data->lend_amount <= 500) {
  $bonus = ($data->lend_amount * 4) / 100;
} else if ($data->lend_amount >= 500 && $data->lend_amount <= 50000) {
  $bonus = ($data->lend_amount * 5) / 100;
}
```

Or set default value in the last else block

```
if ($data->lend_amount >= 50 && $data->lend_amount <= 500) {
  $bonus = ($data->lend_amount * 4) / 100;
} else if ($data->lend_amount >= 500 && $data->lend_amount <= 50000) {
  $bonus = ($data->lend_amount * 5) / 100;
} else {
  $bonus = 0;
}
```

Comment: Sir I want to call $bonus after the if else statement. how to do that?

Comment: You can't call something that doesn't exists. You must to make sure that `$bonus` is  defined before you call it. Take a look at your if-else statement, it's probably doesn't falls true as you expect it. Do you still have an error if use one of my codes?